# Le complément de nom du complément de nom, une question de style

Tags: style-de-rédaction, complément-de-nom

Il arrive que l'on soit amené à ajouter un complément de nom à un autre nom qui est déjà un complément de nom, et une telle extension ne soulève pas de question de style; une itération de cette opération semble commencer à sonner une fin proche au processus d'itération. Un cas tel que

> « la poignée de la porte de la chambre de la suite de l'ambassadeur de La Tanzanie »

a déjà dépassé une limite; on ne peut trouver cinq niveaux que très rarement.

Y a-t-il des principes reconnus relatifs à cette question? Recommande-t-on d'éviter ce type d'enchainement après un nombre donné? Autrement est-ce que la limite serait naturellement fixée en conséquence d'un gout général non reconnu mais que l'expérience de la lecture et de la plume permette à l'utilisateur de la langue d'internaliser? Quelle serait alors cette limite? Certains principes généraux sont-ils conseillés dans le sens de fournir des substituts à des enchainements contenant trop d'itérations d'un complément de nom?

Answer (score 3):

Une limite à 5 ?

Je te répondrai quand j'aurai fini !

*Aurai* correspond bien à la première personne **du** singulier **du** futur **de** l'indicatif **du** verbe **de** la subordonnée circonstancielle **de** temps ? non ?

6!

Et je crois pouvoir trouver facilement mieux en cherchant dans les dérivées de fonctions de... du... de la...

Sans compter l'analyse **de** la dernière note **de** la mesure 224 **de** l'allegro **de** la 27<sup>e</sup> sonate **de** LvB ou les descriptions d'opérations chirurgicales...

---

*la subordonnée circonstancielle **de** temps* Ha... tiens... on trouvera certaines pages dans lesquels l'auteur parle de *subordonnée circonstancielle **temporelle***

Eh oui! Il existe une foultitude d'**adjectifs** parfaitement adaptés à la **réduction** du CN. Ainsi

- Plutôt que de parler de l'*économie **de** la région* on parlera de l'*économie **régionale**.*
- Plutôt que de relater les conditions d'élection du Président de la République du Togo, on parlera d'élection **présidentielle togolaise**.

Les **adjectifs épithètes** voilà les substituts. Sont-ce même des substituts ? Ils sont faits pour cela!

Bon... gaffe quand même à ne pas y aller les yeux fermés... un *correspondant de guerre* n'étant évidemment pas un *correspondant guerrier*... ;-)

=> La limite à l'extension du CN en de + substantif ? :

1/ L'existence d'un adjectif parfaitement adapté
2/ La limite de précision requise.

Comment: On pourrait dire alors que dans les énonciations à caractère technique on ne se soucie pas outre mesure du style et qu'il n'y a pas de limite à laquelle accorder de véritable considération ? Cela néglige le domaine  courant de l'expression écrite (littérature, écrits épistolaires, langue des médias).  La dernière spécification n'est pas claire; en quoi « 1/ » et « 2/ » spécifieraient ou non l'existence de limites admises?

Comment: @LPH La limite 1/ est de simple bon sens et vaut quel que soit le style : S'il existe un mot Y désignant la même chose que  *préposition + Z*, sauf volonté d'une construction particulière on choisit Y. : https://www.persee.fr/doc/lfr_0023-8368_1992_num_96_1_5782

Comment: @LPH et 2/ est une limite admise au sens où elle est imposée par une **exigence** variable en fonction du type de document. Il ne s'agit même pas là d'admettre. Une exigence c'est imposé.

Comment: Il n'y aurait donc en aucun cas de question de lourdeur de style quel que soit le domaine, littérature, écrits techniques ou autre. Est-ce exact selon votre connaissance de la question?

Comment: @LPH : A/ Dans un document analytique, le style doit s'effacer devant les exigences de précision. B/ Dans les documents d'un autre genre, il existe suffisamment d'adjectifs pour autolimiter naturellement les extensions à rallonge cf exemples ci-contre et document suggéré en lien ci-dessus.

Comment: Intégrez s'il vous plait cette dernière  conclusion  assez explicite à votre réponse et je la considèrerai alors comme satisfaisante.

Comment: @aCOSwt – bien dit ! Toutefois, les abréviations des ordinaux sont (norme AFNOR !) : 1er, 1re, 2nd, 2e et ensuite toujours « e », donc « 27e sonate pour piano de Ludwig van » soi-même. C'est mieux, c'est le plus simple, c'est … parfois non respecté.

Comment: @5915961T : Merci! Typo corrigée!